# Send data from Android to Unity when Unity is running on another process

Tags: android, forms, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've a **Xamarin Forms** app where I need to pass data from **Android** to **Unity**, working Unity as a library.

I have used the next code, and it works fine if both are in the same process.

```
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Gameobject", "MyMethod", "Message");
```

But when I change Unity to another process (it is necessary to close the unity scene and return to android previous activity), UnitySendMessage doesn't work.

```
    [Activity(Label = "CustomUnityAndroidActivity", MainLauncher = false, ... , Process = ":unityplayer", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, ...]
```

There is a way to pass data to another process?

Comment: One way of interprocess communication is using a BroadcastReceiver on the receiving-side (Unity) and Activity.sendBroadcast on the broadcasting-side (Xamarin Forms).

Answer (score 0):

If both processes belong to the same application, then the recommended way within android seems to be [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services). To get this running with unity probably involves a significant amount of messing around with the manifests and build configurations, but may be doable.

If you are actually in two separate apps in android then the correct way to do it is with a [content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics). A content provider may still be useful even if you are in the same activity as well. There are limitations with what a content provider can do, but I can guarantee that you can get both sides of a content provider working in unity. [Here](https://github.com/Applicasa/Sample-App-Unity/blob/master/Assets/Plugins/Android/facebook/src/com/facebook/NativeAppCallContentProvider.java) is one example.